# [vtk filters into blender

Tags: blender, vtk

I'm trying to import vtk into Blender to use specific filters. I'm facing some difficulties since Blender is not able to find, and subsequently to use any filter.

Here is the situation:

I've build VTK including the python wrapping. I have DLLs and *.py libraries.
I have created PYTHONPATH and added both Wrapping\python and VTK\Release directories. Python 2.7 has been used to generate *.py VTK libraries. The python 3.4 interpreter (and blender since my version is using a python V3.4 distribution) is able to import the vtk library but gives me an error "Import error: Dynamic module does not define init function(PyInit_vtkCommonCorePython)"

I'm very pessimistic because VTK has been built using python 2.7 and blender uses python 3.4. Python 3.4 canno find the suitable DLL corresponding to the .py since VTK dlls are named "vtkLIBxxx27D-6.1.dll" and specifically dedicated for python 2.7.

Is there a way to force a backward compatibility to blender and its python interpreter to import a python 2.7 library?

Do we have any chance to make vtk (python 2.7) working into blender (python 3.4)?

Thanks for your help.

Laurent.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.6 uses Python 3+, while VTK is wrapped for 2.7. The two APIs are incompatible (hence the major version change in Python).

If your aim is to import vtk polydata into Blender, my suggestion is that you save the VTK files as STL or OBJ (you have VTK writers for both) and import them into Blender that way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a couple of years too late, but Blender and VTK can now use the same Python version, so I've recently updated a script that converts Blender meshes <==> VtkPolyData. If you are interested, the script and a few demos are here:

https://github.com/cwant/VTKBlender

Regards,
Chris